# Store NSDictionary In CoreData ios not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Since I get into a requirement of saving NSDictionary offline and populate the table from it when the user is offline.
This is the code I have so far:

**Everytime the resulting NSDictionary was getting as nil**

I have made this attribute set as transformable

```
 + (void) insertIntoCoredata :(NSString *) table : (NSString *) attribute : (NSArray *) dic  {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate =(AppDelegate*)
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context =
    appDelegate.managedObjectContext;


    NSData *myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dic];


    NSManagedObject *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:table
                                                            inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [object setValue:myData forKey:attribute];
    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to save - error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

}

+ (id) getFromCoredata :(NSString *) table : (NSString *) attribute {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate =(AppDelegate*)
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context =
    appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:table
                                                           inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetch setEntity:entityDescription];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
    if([fetchedObjects count] == 1)
        return [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    else
        return nil;


}
```

What went wrong with this code.

Comment: In `getFromCoredata` you should *fetch* an object, not insert a new one. Have a look at "Fetching Objects" in the Core Data Programming Guide.

Comment: Also looks like your trying to convert an NSArray not a NSDictionary

Comment: @MartinR i have updated code. please check now

Comment: will it loss my NSDictionary Data when converted into NSData

Comment: How I understand the actual question is "Why does `NSData *myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dic];` return `nil`". Am I right?

Comment: Nop NSData conversion is working fine. 1765bytes

Comment: Could you please add to the question your data model file screenshot, or NSManagedObject subclass?